# re-arrange and plot data pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, python-3.5

I have a data frame like the following:

```
   days movements count
0   0   0         2777
1   0   1         51
2   0   2         2
3   1   0         6279
4   1   1         200
5   1   2         7
6   1   3         3
7   2   0         5609
8   2   1         110
9   2   2         32
10  2   3         4
11  3   0         4109
12  3   1         118
13  3   2         101
14  3   3         8
15  3   4         3
16  3   6         1
17  4   0         3034
18  4   1         129
19  4   2         109
20  4   3         6
21  4   4         2
22  4   5         2
23  5   0         2288
24  5   1         131
25  5   2         131
26  5   3         9
27  5   4         2
28  5   5         1
29  6   0         1918
30  6   1         139
31  6   2         109
32  6   3         13
33  6   4         1
34  6   5         1
35  7   0         1442
36  7   1         109
37  7   2         153
38  7   3         13
39  7   4         10
40  7   5         1
41  8   0         1085
42  8   1         76
43  8   2         111
44  8   3         13
45  8   4         7
46  8   7         1
47  9   0         845
48  9   1         81
49  9   2         86
50  9   3         8
51  9   4         8
52  10  0         646
53  10  1         70
54  10  2         83
55  10  3         1
56  10  4         2
57  10  5         1
58  10  6         1
```

This shows that for example on day 0, I have 2777 entries with 0 movements, 51 entries with 1 movement, 2 entries with 2 movements. I want to plot it as bar graph for every day and show the entries count for all movements. In order to do it, I thought I would transform the data to something like below and then plot a bar graph.

```
days 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   2777 51  2                  
1   6279 200 7   3              
2   5609 110 32  4              
3   4109 118 101 8   3          
4   3034 129 109 6   2   2      
5   2288 131 131 9   2   1      
6   1918 139 109 13  1   1      
7   1442 109 153 13  10  1      
8   1085 76  111 13  7           1
9   845  81  86  8   8          
10  646  70  83  1   2   1   1
```

I am not getting an idea of how should I achieve this? I have thousands of lines of data so doing it by hand does not make sense. Can someone guide me how to rearrange the data or if there is a quick way to plot the bar graph using matplotlib straight from the actual data frame that would be even better. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is pivot ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I just used pandas.pivot_table function and it works great. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Wen, I used the following code to generate pivot table

Comment: table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='count', index=['days'],columns=['movements'], aggfunc=np.sum). It does generate pivot table correctly and I can plot the table. But could you guide me how to select a specific column from this table to plot? In the above example, I have 8 columns in the pivot table from 0-7, how would i select column 0 for ploting with plt.plot(x=table.index, y=??)?